# How to use variable from model to controller codeigneter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I have this script in model

```
<?php

class Log_in extends CI_Model
{

    public function sign_in()
    {
        $Email = $this->input->post('Email');

        $this->db-select('Email');
        $this->db-from('users');
        $this->db->where('Email' , $Email);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return $query->result();
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

and this controller

```
<?php

class LogIn_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }   


    public function LogIn(){

        $this->load->model('Log_in');

        if($query){
            echo "login success";
        }else{
            echo "error";
        }

    }
}
```

when I check if(query) codeigneter show error page undefined variable $query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your `LogIn` controller as following

```
public function LogIn(){

    $this->load->model('Log_in');
    $query = $this->Log_in->sign_in();
    if($query){
        echo "login success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

    class LogIn_Controller extends CI_Controller{

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Log_in');//this load your model once
        }


        public function LogIn(){

            $query = $this->Log_in->sign_in();//assign value to query

            if($query)
            {
                echo "login success";
            }else
            {
                echo "error";
            }
        }
    }
```

Read this

1. [CI Model](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)
2. [CI Controller](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Either declare a variable (say `$query` )

```
$query = $this->load->model('Log_in');

    if($query){
        echo "login success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

**OR**

Directly check in the `if` condition

```
    if($this->load->model('Log_in')){
        echo "login success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Undefined variable $query` showing because you didn't declare the variable `"$query"`. You can try the following code :

```
public function LogIn(){

    $this->load->model('Log_in');
    $query = $this->Log_in->sign_in(); // variable $query declared 
    if($query){
        echo "login success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First the call the main model **Log_in** in your controller and after the create one variable and called only the model method... changes your controller as following

```
public function LogIn(){

    $this->load->model('Log_in'); //Load The Model In your construct at Once
    $query = $this->Log_in->sign_in(); //create var and load the model method
    if($query){
        echo "login success";
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }

}
```